# PROTRACTOR - How to handle SSL certificate prompt

Tags: typescript, selenium, automation, protractor

Our applications use SSL certs and we can't bypass chrom's prompt to select cert. We would be happy with just selecting the certificate (its usually one). We have tried things like:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--disable-remote-fonts', '--start-maximized', '--ignore-certificate-errors']
    },
    trustAllSSLCertificates: true,
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS: true,
  }
```

Doesn't work, browser opens and just hangs on cert selection screen despite there is only one cert to be selected.  Can't believe that solution for this doesn't exist for protractor :/ Any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

Its possible to miss the args or just not using the proper key for chrome options.

Try with:

```
trustAllSSLCertificates: true,
acceptInsecureCerts: true,
ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS: true,
'goog:chromeOptions': {
   args: {
     '--disable-infobars',
     '--disable-extensions',
     '--disable-web-security'
   }
}
```